# Create tooltip after setting show hover is true

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

After setting `setShowHover` true, how do I create the tooltip? Right now it is a blank tooltip.

```
 ListGridField exportField = new IconField(FIELD_EXPORT, REDO_ICON.jpg, EXPORT_CUSTOM_GROUP_HANDLER);

exportField.setShowHover(true);
```

Tried  `exportField.setPrompt("a tooltip message");`, but this did not give every single icon a tooltip when i mouse over it.

This a picture showing the tooltip is blank when i hover over the blue-pointer button, the message "a tooltip message" only appear when I hover over the very top blue-pointer button. I want it to show a tooltip for every blue-pointer button.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving the delete button a hover tooltip in gwt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560138/giving-the-delete-button-a-hover-tooltip-in-gwt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `exportField.setHoverCustomizer()` to show a customized prompt message.**

Try this one

```
    ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();

    grid.setCanHover(true);
    grid.setShowHover(true);

    ...

    exportField.setHoverCustomizer(new HoverCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public String hoverHTML(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
            // you can customize the prompt and can get the values from current record also
            return "a tooltip message";
        }
    });
```

Comment: If it doesn't work then let me know how are you creating `IconField`?