# Giving the delete button a hover tooltip in gwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

In this picture, as you can see there are the red deletion buttons, how do I create a hover tooltip for these buttons? Is it the same as `setShowHover(true)`?

[image]

Code:

```
HoverCustomizer customGroupTooltips = new HoverCustomizer()
        {
            @Override
            public String hoverHTML(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
                if (colNum == 1)
                {
                    return "tooltip message";
                }
                else if (colNum == 2)
                {
                    return "delete";
                }
                return null;
            }  
        };

        ListGridField name = new ListGridField(FIELD_NAME);
        ListGridField exportField = new IconField(FIELD_EXPORT, ICON.jpg, EXPORT_CUSTOM);

        exportField.setShowHover(true);
        exportField.setHoverCustomizer(customGroupTooltips.hoverHTML()); //how do i make sure it is colNum 1 message here?
```

Comment: Is it not working as I answered in your last question [Create tooltip after setting show hover is true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543335/create-tooltip-after-setting-show-hover-is-true/22545426#22545426) for the same?

Comment: @Braj, it worked thanks! So can I combine these 2 in one setHoverCustomizer? If so how do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it, What you want to combine? Please explain in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using `setHoverCustomizer()` method on `ListGridField`.

Here is the code:

```
    ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();

    grid.setCanHover(true);
    grid.setShowHover(true);

    ...

    grid.setCanRemoveRecords(true);
    ListGridField ls = new ListGridField();
    grid.setRemoveFieldProperties(ls);
    ls.setHoverCustomizer(new HoverCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public String hoverHTML(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
            return "click here to delete this record";
        }
    });
```

Comment: I added the code i have, so do I have to add another setHoverCustomizer for the deletion button?

Comment: If you have same HTML for both `ListGridField` then you can use same `HoverCustomizer`. Yes you can use same `HoverCustomizer` with different HTML that may contains value from current `ListGridRecord`.

Comment: it's the same HTML, but so if I have to use the same. Do I creatre another hoverHTML() and have it return "deleted"?

Comment: Create an object `hc` of `HoverCustomizer` and set it for multiple `ListGridField` just by calling `listGridField1.setHoverCustomizer(hc);` and `listGridField2.setHoverCustomizer(hc);` and so on...

Comment: You don't need to create another `hoverHTML()`. Its a method not an object.

Comment: Ok, so how does it know when to return "deleted" or "just a tooltip"?

Comment: `colNum` starts from 0. It will be 2 in this case for delete icon.

Comment: so I made if colNum == 1 return a message, if ==2, return a message.
setHoverCustomizer(customGroupTooltips.hoverHTML()); ?

Comment: I will be more clear for others also if you paste some code in your question itself. It seems you are doing correct.

Comment: just added the code, from that, how do I give column 2 (the deletion buttons) the delete message?

Comment: Just single change replace `exportField.setHoverCustomizer(customGroupTooltips.hoverHTML());` with `exportField.setHoverCustomizer(customGroupTooltips);` Every this handled in `hoverHTML` itself based on hover position.

Comment: The delete message is not showing up, is it because I didnt add setRemoveFieldProperties(exportField)?

Comment: You have to set it. I have already shared you a working sample code. Just read it again and follow it. Examine what are you missing.

Comment: `setRemoveFieldProperties(exportField)` is wrong. You have to call `setRemoveFieldProperties(ls)`.

Comment: ListGridField ls = new ListGridField();
        setRemoveFieldProperties(ls);
        exportField.setHoverCustomizer(customGroupTooltips);
        ls.setHoverCustomizer(customGroupTooltips);
it's not showing the delete message still

Comment: Have you called `grid.setCanHover(true);` and   `grid.setShowHover(true);` and `ls.setShowHover(true);`